# Rails Validates uniqueness of a column based on a relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have a product table which belongs to market & has many variants, every variants has SKU column, i want to validates uniqueness of sku but for the same market. i've tried

```
validates :sku, uniqueness: { scope: :market_id }
```

but since variant doesn't have market_id column it doesn't work!!, how can i overcome this issue ?!

Answer (score 1):

Although you can access variants from market, 
if you set you relations with has many through, but
my opinion it's better to save market_id inside variants table and set index based two column

```
class Market < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
  has_many :variants , :through => :products
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :market
  has_many :variants
end

class Variant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :Product
end
```

You can generate migration to add market_id in variants table 
with index based two column
[here is the reference](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index) 
and here is the code to generate index based two columnn(market_id and sku)

```
add_index(:variants, [:market_id, :sku], unique: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant belongs to a product in a certain market, therefore, in order to avoid an extra join (which is a costly operation) when retrieving a variant of a product in a market, and in order to implement this validation, the schema should be designed in a way that `Variant` should belong to both `Market` and `Product`.

If a Variant belongs both to `Product` and `Market`, the validation would be as follows

```
validates_uniqueness_of :sku, scope: [:market_id, :product_id]
```